# Angular 2+ - modal component rendered always at same place

Tags: angular, angular-routing, router-outlet

I'm currently solving quite tricky problem. I would like to have in my root app.component.html place, where will be rendered modal window, but I would like to use named router-routlets as well to have this modal available through URL.

My router array looks like:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/admin/orders', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'admin/orders',
    component: OrdersComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      { path: '', component: OrderListComponent },
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: OrderDetailComponent,
        outlet: 'modal'
      }
    ]
  },
  { path: 'admin/stats', canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: StatsComponent },
  { path: 'admin/settings', canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: SettingsComponent },
  { path: 'admin/user', canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: UserComponent },
  { path: 'auth', component: AuthComponent }
];
```

So challenge is to render OrderDetailComponent somehow here into app.component.html:

```
<div class="app">
  <app-navigation></app-navigation>
  <app-header></app-header>
  <main class="app__content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </main>
  <!-- HERE I WANT TO RENDER MODAL CONTENT -->
</div>
```

Of course one way to solve this is to have another route path of OrdersComponent like this:

```
  {
    path: 'admin/orders',
    component: OrdersComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    outlet: 'modal',
    children: [
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: OrderDetailComponent,
      }
    ]
  }
```

and then in app.component.html:

```
<div class="app">
  <app-navigation></app-navigation>
  <app-header></app-header>
  <main class="app__content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </main>
  <router-outlet name="modal"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

But the problem here is that it will call me twice AuthGuard.

I would appreciate any suggestion which will lead me how to solve this correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will doing the following not solve it?

```
<div class="app">
  <app-navigation></app-navigation>
  <app-header></app-header>
  <main class="app__content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </main>
  <app-order-detail></app-order-detail>
</div>
```

Then use *ngIf to render the component based on whatever condition is relevant.

Comment: Well, I guess it's an option, but if I'll add new components which I would like to render on this place, the only way will be to add here each of them (or wrap it to another component), but I guess there is not too much components I'd like to render here, so I'll use it like that :) Thanks anyway